# how to print project name on blade file Laravel 5.2

Tags: php, laravel-5

I need print My project name and task name on subtask blade file. My problem is this, I have project management app and its contain projects and one project have many tasks and one task have many subtasks. this is my relationship between task and subtasks task model

```
Task Model
    public function subtasks(){
        return $this->hasMany(Subtask::class);
    }



Subtask model
    public function task(){
        return $this->belongsTo(Task::class);
    }
```

and my subtask data input file is :

`subtask/form.blade.php`

```
<h4>Add Sub Task</h4>
 <form class="form-vertical" role="form" method="post" action="{{ route('subtasks.form', ['projectId'=> $projectId, 'taskId'=>$taskId])}}">
     <div class="form-group{{ $errors->has('name') ? ' has-error' : '' }}">
     <input type="text" name="task_name" class="form-control" id="name" value="{{ old('task_name') ?: '' }}">
     @if ($errors->has('task_name'))
         <span class="help-block">{{ $errors->first('task_name') }}</span>
     @endif
     </div>
     <div class="form-group">
         <button type="submit" class="btn btn-info">Create Task</button>
     </div>
     <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{ csrf_token() }}">
 </form>
```

this is my subtaskcontroller

```
public function store(Request $request,$projectId,$taskId)
    {
        $subtask = new Subtask;
        $subtask->subtask_name = $request->input('task_name');
        $subtask->task_id = $taskId;
        $subtask->project_id = $projectId;

        $subtask->save();
        //
    }
```

I need print My project name and task name on the subtask.blade.php how can I do this?
**Edited**
please see my controller show

```
public function show($id)
    {
        $task = $subtask->task;
        $project = $task->project;
        return view('subtasks.form', ['subtask' => $subtask, 'task' => $task, 'project => $project]);
        //
    }
```

how should I replase **show($id)** here

**Edited subtask store method**

```
 public function store(Request $request,$projectId,$taskId)
    {
        $subtask = new Subtask;
        $subtask->subtask_name = $request->input('task_name');
        $subtask->task_id = $taskId;
        $subtask->project_id = $projectId;

        $subtask->save();
        //
    }
```

**subtask show method**

```
public function show($id)
{
    $subtask = Subtask::findOrFail($id);
    $task = $subtask->task;
    $project = $task->project;
    return view('subtasks.form', ['subtask' => $subtask, 'task' => $task, 'project => $project]);
    //
}
```

Comment: No any idea....

Comment: Can you paste the subtask 'show' method

Comment: I paste subtask 'show' method

Comment: do you have any idea?

Comment: I've edited my answer with the tested solution from my dev environment

Answer (score 0):

### Edited Answer

Starting with migrations:

**Projects Table**

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('projects', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->string('name');
        $table->text('description');
        $table->timestamps();
    });
}
```

**Tasks Table**

```
public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('tasks', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->integer('project_id')->index();
            $table->string('name');
            $table->text('description');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }
```

**Subtasks Table**

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('subtasks', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->integer('task_id')->index();
        $table->string('name');
        $table->string('status');
        $table->timestamps();
    });
}
```

Then the Controllers:

**SubtaskController**

Ensure the `store` method contains the related task id.

```
public function store(Request $request,$projectId,$taskId)
    {
    $subtask = new Subtask();

    $subtask->name = 'Subtask A';
    $subtask->task_id = '1';
    $subtask->status = 'New';
    $subtask->save();
    }
```

Same idea for the TaskController, ensure project_id is saved with object.

The subtask `show` method:

```
public function show($id)
    {
        $subtask = Subtask::findOrFail($id);
        $task = $subtask->task;
        $project = $task->project;

        return view('subtask-view', ['subtask' => $subtask, 'task' => $task, 'project' => $project]); 
}
```

Then in your view:

```
{{ $subtask->name }} belongs to {{ $task->name }} which is a part of {{ $project->name }}
```

Comment: My project Model relationship as this **public function tasks(){
         return $this->hasMany('App\Task');
}** is this correct?

Comment: Yes, sorry - I've just made a correction.  You need the relationship from your Task model to the Project model.  So in your Task model, the task 'belongs to' the project.  In other words, the inverse of the relationship above in the comment.

Comment: My relationship as this ** return $this->belongsTo('App\Project');** your way is ** return $this->belongsTo(Project::class);** is both same or not?

Comment: They are both the same, just a different way of referencing the class.  Result is the same though.

Comment: do you have any idea?

Comment: I've added an 'Update' at the end of the answer

Comment: I am going to print task name witch related to subtask as this **{{ $task->name }}** but got error messages this **Undefined variable: task**

Comment: Did you add this line into the show method?  $subtask = Subtask::findOrFail($id);